# Error running Play2 app with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

After running my Play application I receive the error message `Error running MyApp: Play 2 isn't installed` (where MyApp is my app's name) and a SBT background task (`SBT: Waiting for lock on /Users/mhp/.sbt/boot/sbt.boot.lock to be available...`) is running continuously.

I've installed the Play Framework via homebrew, so that I setup the Play home directory to `/usr/local/Cellar/play/2.2.1/bin`. However, I still get the error.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---- Update

The root cause is you didn't set the global path of "PLAY_HOME".

This problem can be resolved by adding the "PLAY_HOME" variable to your global path (of your system, like JAVA_HOME).

---- Original

I am using Fedora 19 and having this issue for a long time since version 12. Now I am using the Intellij 13, still the same thing.

Every time the new configuration will need to be modified manually. Not just me, but also others.

I have tried both the projects created by Play and Intellij, none of them can work out of the box.

Comment: What do you had to configure?

Comment: Try "Edit Configurations", check box "Use non-default Play 2 install dir", put your play installation directory there. You can also try to set $PLAY_HOME to you path configuration, it worked for some people.

Comment: Hey! So I've added the `PLAY_HOME` path variable under windows and it works fine. I'll try it later on my Mac! Thumbs up :)

Comment: I'm afraid that works only under Windows. Unfortunately nothing changed on my MacBook.. Thank you anyway! +1

Comment: Hi @mhp, can you try "echo $PLAY_HOME" to check if the variable is set properly? Also you should check that "echo $PATH" contains the path of play (which should be "/usr/local/Cellar/play/2.2.1").

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IntelliJ 13, create your Play! project with the command line. Then go into intelliJ, choose Open, select the `build.sbt` file and let the software do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

In Edit configurations of Play 2 App check

```
"Use non-default Play 2 install dir"
```

and set the value to

```
/usr/local/Cellar/play/2.2.1/
```

Comment: That did not work :( What is the purpose of the Play working directory which I can configure in the IntelliJ settings?

Comment: Can you confirm that /usr/local/Cellar/play/2.2.1/play is executable for user you run intellij with? (e.g. with ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/play/2.2.1/play, you should see something like -rwxr-xr-- .......)

Comment: Unfortunately these settings are correct, so there might be something else what is maybe wrong.. I just discovered that the play file within the /usr/local/Cellar/play/2.2.1/bin directory is a symlink to the /usr/local/Cellar/play/2.2.1/libexec directory. However, setting the the libexec as working directory didn't changed anything.. I think I'm stuck here!

Comment: Yep, seems that intellij is not compatible with the homebrew version. You can try to install play from official distribution, it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Okay, I've installed the Play Framework from official distribution. I additionally set the PATH variable. But it didn't helped :( When I now using the `play` command from the console I get the following `error: usage: dirname path`
`Error: Unable to access jarfile /framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar`

Comment: Have you done all from http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Installing?

Comment: Yes sir! I just found out that spaces in directories are not welcome by the Play script. So I'm able to access `play`via the console finally. However, IntelliJ does not work..

Comment: Still the same what I mentioned in my origin question. In IntelliJ nothing changed..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42798/discussion-between-frant-hartm-and-mhp)

Answer (score 1):

> SBT: Waiting for lock on /Users/mhp/.sbt/boot/sbt.boot.lock to be available...

Seems that other sbt running in parallel.

Also try to create idea project by play command:

```
cd project/
play 'idea with-sources=yes'
```

If `play` not in your PATH, use full path.

Than open generated project in Idea and add 'Play 2 App' run configuration (Run -> Edit configuration ...).